# Show that $a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1=\gcd(a^m-1,a^n-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $c_n$ be sequence defined for $n\ge 1$ as follows:
$$ c_n=a^n-1.$$

Prove that this sequence satifies strong divisibility condition, that is:
$$ \gcd(c_n, c_m)=c_{\gcd(n,m)}.$$

where $\gcd$ denotes greatest common divisor. Any hints?

Comment: Can you show that $a^{(m,n)}-1$ divides the two at least?

Comment: Hints? Well $a^k - 1 = (a -1)(a^{k-1} + ..... + 1$ so $a^{dm} - 1 = (a^d - 1)(a^{(m-1)d} + .... + 1$.  So $a^d - 1$ will divide all $a^{dk} - 1$